# Blender script + EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, error

I have a script running in Pyside2 in its own thread, its persistent window that never closes and remain in that thread during the blender live cycle.

When I try to run a render via `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=1)` there is 50% chance I get

```
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF765FF38B0
Module  : C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\blender.exe
```

I’m guessing its due to some thread synchronization or something, as this "Addon" does not align too properly to blender addon guide as I’m using PySide2.

In any case, does any1 have any idea why I'm getting these crashes when I try to render? How can I tell blender to render from other thread? As far as I can tell when the render "works" the Qt GUI becomes frozen, but blender gui still remains "responsive" which tells me that I must be starting the render from Qt thread and not blender own thread & causing an error...

Any hints would be great
TIA.

edit. my render script goes as follow:

```
    for camera in cameraList:
        bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
        bpy.context.scene.camera = bpy.data.objects[camera]
        bpy.data.scenes[0].render.filepath = self.mRootPath + "/" + str(camera) + "." + self.mFormat
        print("render", self.mRootPath + "/" + str(camera) + "." + self.mFormat)
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=1)
        print("pass render ")
```

error happens on `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=1)`

Comment: do you test run only the bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=1)  line?

Comment: you should  see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html?highlight=thread at the end of page

Comment: or https://devtalk.blender.org/t/multithreading-support-please/13038